# nginx fails with following error: nginx: [alert] perl_parse() failed: 2

Tags: centos, systemd, perl, nginx

I have nginx version 1.10.2 running on a CentOS 7 box. When I try to start the service I am getting the following error:

```
Aug 15 16:08:50 user.mylabserver.com nginx[2704]: Can't locate nginx.pm in 
@INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vend
Aug 15 16:08:50 user.mylabserver.com nginx[2704]: BEGIN failed--compilation 
aborted.
Aug 15 16:08:50 user.mylabserver.com nginx[2704]: nginx: [alert] 
perl_parse() failed: 2
Aug 15 16:08:50 user.mylabserver.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: main process 
exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 15 16:08:50 user.mylabserver.com systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered 
failed state.
Aug 15 16:08:50 user.mylabserver.com systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant portion of the log is:

```
Aug 15 16:08:50 user.mylabserver.com nginx[2704]: Can't locate nginx.pm in 
@INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vend
```

The first line indicates that the service startup is failing because it cannot locate the file `nginx.pm`.

The remainder indicates with specificity the exact locations in which is it seeking that file.

If that file does not exist in any of those directories, it appears that either a component of the service has been (re)moved

If it does exist, it is likely that you are not starting the service with a user who has permissions to see or read the required file.

Comment: Yes, it turned out that I was starting the service with the nginx user and the `nginx.pm` file has root ownership. Silly mistake. Thanks for your help!